# Elevenlabs API - Error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/h1YH6feHIpk966qs5vt1/stream

Tags: python, json

I have been experimenting with the API of Elevenlabs, but when I want to use a sentence that is longer than just a couple of words, it only works occasionally and most of the time I get this error:

> Error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
> https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/h1YH6feHIpk966qs5vt1/stream

My only guess it that there is some sort of characters-per-time limit. On the website you have a 2500-character limit, but I couldn't find anything written about a limit in the documentation. Does anybody have experience with this?

My code:

```
from elevenlabslib import *
import os

def get_path():
    return input('Path: ')

user = ElevenLabsUser('<API_KEY>')

voice = user.get_voices_by_name('Adam')[0]

text = 'In botany, a tree is a perennial plant with an elongated stem, or trunk, usually supporting branches and leaves. In some usages, the definition of a tree may be narrower, including only woody plants with secondary growth, plants that are usable as lumber or plants above a specified height. In wider definitions, the taller palms, tree ferns, bananas, and bamboos are also trees.'

path = get_path()
while not os.path.exists(path):
    print('Path does not exist')
    path = get_path()

path.replace('\\', '/')

if path[-1] != '/':
    path += '/'

name = input('File name: ')
if name[-4:] != '.mp3':
    name += '.mp3'

with open(path + name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(voice.generate_audio_bytes(text))
    f.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you trim the text to under 2500 characters? Like submitting `voice.generate_audio_bytes(text[:2499])` versus with just text?

Comment: Have you found the solution? For me this error started happening today even with short messages

Comment: Have you tried changing the IP from the device? They probably rate limit repetitive requests.

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was caused by violating general limit for the subscription plan